# Unable to PUSH nupkg to the existing feed in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

I'm trying to PUSH a nupkg to exisiting Feed in Azure DevOps. When I do it using Powershell scripts, I get the error 'The Specified source is invalid.Provide a valid source' even though the source is valid. When I try to recreate a source with the below command, It gives me error 'The source specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Provide a unique source.'

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [NuGet push command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push), the `Source` option value should be a URL. Besides, the order of the command line options might be different.

I would try to re-write it as follows:

```
nuget.exe push ALS.Library.1.0.0.nupkg -Source "http://..." -ApiKey "..."
```

Comment: This was my problem and fix.  The screwed up part is the Microsoft example in azure for the project claims the project name is enough, which does work until you rename the project.  But as soon as I put in the full .json URL, it worked fine.